# How to split Html String Based on Html tag

Tags: java, android

I have String with Html format. My Html can contains any tags like image , video , ...
I can now handle image and text like this correctly :
I have a textView in my xml:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(DetailActivity.this);

    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(content, new Html.ImageGetter() {


        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {

            try {
                URI uri = new URI(source);
                URL videoUrl = uri.toURL();
                File tempFile = new File(videoUrl.getFile());
                filename = tempFile.getName();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            Drawable drawable = null;
            ContextWrapper cw1 = new ContextWrapper(DetailActivity.this);
            File directory1 = cw1.getDir("multiImage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final File myImageFile1 = new File(directory1, filename);
            File f = new File(myImageFile1.getAbsolutePath());

            Log.i("multiImage", filename);
            final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(DetailActivity.this);

            if (f.exists()) {

                drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(myImageFile1.getAbsolutePath());

                //drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), drawable.getIntrinsicWidth());
                int imgH = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                int imgW = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                int padding = 20;
                int realWidth = ScreenW - (2 * padding);
                int realHeight = imgH * realWidth / imgW;
                drawable.setBounds(padding, 0, realWidth, realHeight);


            } else {

                Picasso.with(DetailActivity.this)
                        .load(source)
                        .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {


                                BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
                                Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();

                                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                                File outFile = new File(myImageFile1.getAbsolutePath());
                                try {
                                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
                                try {
                                    outStream.flush();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                try {
                                    outStream.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onError() {

                            }
                        });

                URL sourceURL;
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                try {
                    sourceURL = new URL(source);
                    URLConnection urlConnection = sourceURL.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.connect();
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream =
                            new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

                    // convert Bitmap to Drawable
                    drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);

                    int imgH = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    int imgW = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                    int padding = 20;
                    int realWidth = ScreenW - (2 * padding);
                    int realHeight = imgH * realWidth / imgW;
                    drawable.setBounds(padding, 0, realWidth, realHeight);


                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


            return drawable;
        }

    }, new UlTagHandler()));
```

But I can not show video using above code. 
I want to split my string --> from the first until the video tag and then video tag at the end of video tag and the rest of string .

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But at first glance I don't see where you split a HTML string. It may be that you are implicitly doing this somewhere. But it would be nicer here if you could reduce it to a minimal yet complete example

Comment: now in this code , i do not split . I dont know how to split my string into several string